# How to create a managed package for use within a single organization?

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

I need to create a reusable component that would only be used by other developers within a single SalesForce organization. The component is made up of VisualForce pages and Apex code. I believe this would normally be done as a managed package in ISVForce, but my understanding is that ISVForce requires additional reviews and this package is only for internal use - it shouldn't be listed on the App Exchange.

Is there a notion of managed packages for internal reuse? Or is there some other way to create distributable, closed-source packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple create a managed package and install it to your org via **install link**, this way do not require security review because you do not need to publish your package in AppExchange. Just read a [manual about creating managed package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=enabling_managed_packages.htm&language=en_US). I do believe that a creation of managed package without publishing in AppExchange is pretty simple and straightforward and that's what you really need